# How to create a regular expression to find out repeated character in string?

Tags: ios, swift

Eg:

1. HelloWorld - repeated characters are 5 (l is repeating 3 times and o is repeating 2 times)
2. Smart2000,  repeated characters = 3?(0 is repeating 3 times)
3. Smart@200@12, repeated characters = 6

I tried with iterating over string

Here is my code with string iteration to find out the repeated character in string.

```
func countRepeatDigitsIn(keyword : String) -> Int
{
    // To keep track of processed symbols
    var uniqueCharacters = ""
    var repeatCharacterCount = 0

    for char in keyword.uppercased() {
        let alphabet = String(char)

        // If this is already counted, skip it
        if (uniqueCharacters.contains(alphabet))
        {
            repeatCharacterCount += 1
        }

        // Otherwise, add it to processed symbols
        uniqueCharacters += alphabet
    }

    return repeatCharacterCount
}
```

Comment: Regular expression is not what you want for this.

Comment: Do not prejudge the best way by deciding beforehand that a regular expression is best. Just ask your question and show some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> HelloWorld - repeated characters are 5 (l is repeating 3 times and o is repeating 2 times

The simplest way to get that result is to take a histogram and then add up all the values that are not 1.

Example:

```
func histogram(_ s:String) -> [Character:Int] {
    var d = [Character:Int]()
    for c in s {
        d[c, default:0] += 1
    }
    return d
}
let reps = histogram("helloworld").values.filter{$0 > 1}.reduce(0, +) // 5
let reps2 = histogram("smart2000").values.filter{$0 > 1}.reduce(0, +) // 3
let reps3 = histogram("Smart@200@12").values.filter{$0 > 1}.reduce(0, +) // 6
```

Comment: +1 for the solution. How about using `reduce` directly on character count dictionary as `histogram("helloworld").reduce(0, { $0 + ($1.value > 1 ? $1.value : 0)})`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fun chain of reductions and filters on the characters of the string.

```
func countRepeatDigitsIn(keyword : String) -> Int {
    let total = Array(keyword.uppercased()).reduce(into: [Character : Int]()) { $0[$1, default: 0] += 1 }.filter { $0.value > 1 }.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.value }

    return total
}

for text in ["HelloWorld", "Smart2000", "Smart@200@12"] {
    print(text, countRepeatDigitsIn(keyword: text))
}
```

The first `reduce` builds a dictionary where the keys are characters and the values is the count for the character. Then the filter removes characters only found once. The second reduce adds the remaining counts.

Answer (score 0):

Group same characters in a dictionary using [Dictionary(grouping:by:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127163-init) and add the counts of values where the count is greater than 1

```
extension String {
    func repeatCount() -> Int {
        return Dictionary(grouping: lowercased()) { $0 }.values.filter { $0.count > 1 }.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.count }
    }
}
print("HelloWorLd".repeatCount())//5
print("Smart2000".repeatCount())//3
print("Smart@200@12".repeatCount())//6
```